# Scroll first listbox item into view

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox, .net-4.5

I maintain a legacy application and have a request to add a feature.I have a listbox showing some items. When the Itemssource is changed, I want the listbox to scroll to the top.

To do this I have subscriped to the event:

```
private bool handlerAdded = false;
private void KommentarListBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (handlerAdded) { return; }
    var dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, typeof(ListView));
    if (dpd != null)
    {
        dpd.AddValueChanged(KommentarListBox, KommentarListBox_ItemsSourceChanged);
    }
    handlerAdded = true;
}
```

And the event handler:

```
private void KommentarListBox_ItemsSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (KommentarListBox.ItemsSource == null) { return; }
    object item = null;
    foreach (var i in KommentarListBox.ItemsSource)
    {
        item = i;
        break;
    }
    if (item != null)
    {
        KommentarListBox.ScrollIntoView(item);
    }
}
```

However, this does not scroll up. If I call the event handler manually, e.g. by pushing a button, it works. So for the fun of it, I tried doing it from another thread with a sleep in it, and to my surprise it also works. This however is a code smell I'd rather not leave in the codebase. I suspect that the event handler is called before the UI has had a chance to update the UI, but I am not sure. Anyone know how to solve this more robustly, than the dreaded sleep, and know what is happening?

### Solution

The problem was as suspected a matter of trying to scroll before the UI had the chance to update. So using the Dispatcher we can set the priority such that the UI is updated before the we try to scroll the item into view.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => KommentarListBox.ScrollIntoView(item)), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, null);
```

Comment: You are probably trying to call it in window constructor. Do so in `Loaded`.

Comment: It gets called correctly when the ItemsSource is updated. It just doesn't scroll to the top.

Comment: Try to set `ItemsSource` after form is loaded (aka in `Loaded`).

Comment: The ItemsSource is set with databinding, so I cannot control when it is really set other than when the base object changes.

Comment: Then simply call event handler at the end of `Loaded`. More clean would be to create separate method `ScrollToTop()` and call it from property changed event and directly once in `Loaded`.

Comment: That is basically what I am doing. In the `Loaded` event of the ListBox, I subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event, and on that event I try to scroll into view.

That said, the problem was, as suspected, the order of execution. I will modify the post to reflect the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling the ScrollIntoView function directly, try calling it through the dispatcher.
For a winforms app this would be:

```
BeginInvoke((Action)(() => KommentarListBox.ScrollIntoView(item)));
```

Comment: Your suggestion did not solve the problem, but it did lead me to a solution. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it will have to be:

```
if (KommentarListBox.Items.Count > 0)
    lstBox.ScrollIntoView(KommentarListBox.Items[0]);
```

I agree with Sinatr last comment by creating the separate method and calling it twice, once in the event handler and once at the end of the Loaded event.

Comment: the problem being the ItemSourceChanged doesn't fire automatically?

Comment: No, the event fires correctly, and the code is executed. I suspect that it is called before the UI has had a change to update, and for obvious reasons cannot scroll it into view. I have figured a way out and will update the post in a few minuts.